# Cannot Register Windows.Devices.Bluetooth

Tags: c#, windows, dll, bluetooth

I have been trying to register the `Windows.Devices.Bluetooth`, so that I can work with the code found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.bluetooth.rfcomm.aspx

Even though I have the SDKs installed from VS 2013 Pro Update 3, and the Windows 8 SDKs, the only place I have found these assemblies is in the C:\Windows\System32 folder.

When I try to register them into my project I am getting "A Reference to 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.dll' could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."

I have tried this when running VS as admin and without.

Anyone else have this issue, and how did you get over this obstacle?

Comment: I have grabbed a sample from MS that does load with those assemblies, but the dependency is a library called 'Windows.winmd'. That dependency does not seem to like desktop apps.

Comment: Added <TargetPlatformVersion>8.0</TargetPlatformVersion> to the csproj. So I can add Windows.winmd, but still cannot add Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.

Comment: Apparently registering Windows.winmd gives me access to the deviced.bluetooth. However I cannot compile due to Error 1 The type 'System.Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The reference is there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is a combination of everything.

1. Add `<TargetPlatformVersion>8.0</TargetPlatformVersion>` to the csproj
2. Add 'Windows.winmd' to your references.
3. Add C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Facades\System.Runtime.dll to the references.

The default System.Runtime that is part of core does not contain the System.Attribute that the Windows.winmd needs to do anything.

This means that I can now build desktop console applications to work with bluetooth as long as my deployment target is Windows 8.0 and higher.

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question. I've made progress thanks to you but am unfortunately still stuck. This website helped me with the first two steps: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-winrt-apis-from-desktop-applications .

You mention in one of your comments "Apparently registering Windows.winmd give me access to the devices.bluetooth". Can you explain this more? I've done all 3 steps you've mentioned but I cannot add the bluetooth assembly.

Comment: I believe I've solved the issue. Changing the TargetPlatformVersion to 8.1 seems to have given me access to the bluetooth namespace.

Comment: I never finished this project, due to time constraints. But I am glad to hear about your progress.

Answer (score 0):

Change the TargetPlatformVersion to 8.1